# Find rss feed by search query

Tags: android, rss, rss-reader

Looking on some rss apps in store, i found out, that some of them allow to user to type text in search rss editbox, and then show the list of founded rss feeds.
How does they do that?
Is there exists some free public api, for searching a rss feeds??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they use different APIs for that, check out [Google feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) for more information.

Here's the developer's guide. It's pretty straightforward:
https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide

I'm actually developing a RSS APP for android myself, don't hesitate to ask me anything should you need some help :)

Comment: what http referer did you use in your app? did you use userip?

Comment: I haven't implemented any so far, but I will. userip sounds like the best choice. I found this code snippet about how to get the IP address of a your android device. All we have to do is append it to the url. http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/obtaining-your-ip-address-on-android/

Comment: thanks. docs says : `Applications MUST always include a valid and accurate HTTP referer header in their requests.` i wondering, what should i pass in there, package name maybe

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Yeah, I guess your package name should do the trick, but **I'm not certain about this**. I will do some research and let you know if I find anything.